# Using optional parameters in python functions

Tags: python, function

I have this function:

```
def get_previous_backups(backup_dir, extension):
    """Returns a list of backup files matching the date format and file extension"""
    return [os.path.basename(x) for x in
            glob.glob(backup_dir + DIR_PATH + host + '.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' +
                '-[0-9][0-9]' + '-[0-9][0-9]' + '.' + extension)]
```

This function searches in a given directory for files matching the given pattern. Later the results will be used to remove the oldest file. Files like *mx01.2015-10-15.tar.bz2* would match the filter. So the function works like a charm, but here is my problem. This function is part of a backup script I wrote. It makes incremental and full backups. The full backups have a slightly different name. In front of the date of the tar file is a *_FULL* to make it clear that this file contains a complete backup of a system. These files should be removed too. I've tried to use an optional parameter for the function like

`def get_previous_backups(backup_dir, extension, full=None):`

and using it in the concatenation like:

`'-[0-9][0-9]' + '-[0-9][0-9]' + full + '.' + extension)]`

or with format

`'-[0-9][0-9]' + '-[0-9][0-9]' + {} + '.' + extension)].format(full)`

But that didn't work because you can't concatenate dicts or nontype objects with strings.
So my question now is:

Is there a possibility to realise this within this one function, or do I have to use a second one just for the full backups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `None` use `""`, so you can concatenate:

```
def get_previous_backups(backup_dir, extension, full=""):
```